# Mouse tilt buttons only work when window is not "active"?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, mouse

For some reason I have a window where when it is active and I am working within it the vertical scroll will work on my mouse but not horizontal. When I click out of the window and mouseover it both scroll functions will work. Im not sure if it is a setting or not but it only does this with Microsoft Excel. Every other application works fine when the window is selected.

Comment: I am not sure it there is an issue or not. Your mouse would have a driver - did you update it?

Comment: There is definitely an issue if the horizontal scroll function doesn't work. I have the most up to date version of the drivers but it's not a global issue. Just localized to Microsoft Excel. Other Microsoft apps work as well as all other non-Microsoft apps. I'm thinking the issue is not with the mouse but maybe Excel. The buttons mapped to media controls on my mouse also do not work while the excel window is active but do work when it's not.

Comment: I do not know further since the driver is up to date. Perhaps enquire at the Mouse Manufacturer's suipport website.

Comment: If the mouse has related forum support, I suggest you confirm it.